ReWrite with htaccess. Everything works except for one specific url
I use htaccess for the rewrite so that we get a seofriendly url. This works perfectly for a lot of urls, such as:
https://www.example.com/contact will be a redirect to: https://www.example.com/index.php?page=contact
However with one url it goes wrong and just can't figure out why:
https://www.example.com/luistercijfers doesn't work, I get 403 forbidden. In the url bar it says: https://www.example.com/luistercijfers/?page=luistercijfers
This line should handle it: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
Anyone have any idea why only this url doesn't work?
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
  RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^regionieuws/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=regionieuwscontent&Id=$1
  RewriteRule ^agenda/(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=infotheekcontent&Id=$1
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>


There is no apparent reason for this in the setup you have shown us so far, and according to https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=25ded51e-c291-48a1-bc60-0d127d7ee8af it should not happen either. (That tool is not perfect, and can give false results for more complex setups, or when environment variables it doesn't know about are involved - but here, I'd say it confirms that there is nothing wrong with the rewite setup as shown, per se.)

Does a folder of the name luistercijfers actually physically exist, perhaps? Then mod_dir with the default setting DirectorySlash On is probably interfering here. (That would explain the external redirect that is happening - your rewrite setup wouldn't, because apart from the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, those are all internal rewrites only.)

@C3roe: You are right! How silly of me, there is indeed a folder with this name. Thank you so much!
